# how do you change the OS to ubuntu on a MacBook

Tags: boot, usb, macbook

I want to entirely replace OSX10.6.8 (Snow Leopard) on a 2006 13" A1181 MacBook with Ubuntu 20.04.1. I have prepared a USB using Etcher and successfully tried it out, without installing it, on my 2013 MacBook Air.  When I try to boot from the USB on the old MacBook it does not show up on the Boot Disk menu which appears if I hold down the option key at startup. I've done the same thing with a DVD and that doesn't show up either.

The OS on the USB gives the option to try or to install and I want to install this time. Do I have to erase the MacBook's HD first for instance?

I need to know how to proceed - thank you.

Comment: You'll likely need to use [rEFInd](https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html). Note that even though Ubuntu is *relatively* lightweight a 14 year old underpowered laptop may struggle to run it. If that's the case have a look at Xubuntu or Lubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

The Installer will allow you to Format the disk if it can be detected. If you already have a backup of your Mac then you can try to install from the Live instance. Be sure that your processor matches, and perhaps use an older version of Ubuntu since your device might not be supported.

If it turns out that it doesn't work then Fedora might work better. Ubuntu has stricter packaging requirements, whereas you can take an old Fedora image that is compatible or LTS and upgrade with backports. Ubuntu is the most popular and has the majority of desktops, but Fedora is no hassle to the point that Linus uses it.

Comment: I should have said that I was a real beginner.  Maybe trying Ubuntu on an elderly MacBook isn't my best idea.  I want to do a dry run with something and keep my work computers out of it so as not to risk messing them up until I am more confident about using Ubuntu for personal and work use. In this place I don't even understand most of the questions! Nor do I know what a Live instance is.  Yours is a useful answer though because I now know I may need to use an older version of the OS.  How do I find out the latest OS which will run on this old MacBook?